# Most suitable place to store programdata for use over network

Tags: windows, storage, crm, datastore

I am currently working on a CRM application. The application is meant for multiple users, so I need a suitable folder to store things like documents, notes and most importantly the database. This folder should be shared across all users and over network as well.

After searching online it seemed this folder is recommended: "C:\Users\Public\Public Documents". However, this seems like a rather 'hard to find' folder for our customers, who are for the most part little to no experience with computers.

Our non-programmer suggested simply using "C:\CRM\", since it is very easy to find even for new users (and unlikely to be forgotten during a backup!)

I've been trying to find out what the (technical) ups and downs about these two folders are, but I'm finding it hard to get a clear answer. So bassicaly my question is:

Can anyone explain to me why I shouldn't use "C:\CRM\", but I should use "C:\Users\Public\Public"? And what problems I could run into when I do use "C:\CRM\"?

Thanks in advance!